# How to use Multiple custom .less files in Magento 2 using Grunt.js

Tags: magento2, frontend, less, development, grunt

We are developing a custom theme for our Front Store view so we need to use multiple .less files in *web/css/source*. with the help of Grunt.js, the development makes us faster than manually generating less to CSS. so when I run the grunt watch:our-theme command only the _extend.less file compiles to the pub directory

so I need clarification about Grunt.js and how to set up with multiple custom .less files in the configuration
[image: local-themes.js]

**local-theme.js under the dev/tools/grunt/configs**

[image: custom.less]

[image: _extend.less]

**_extend.less**

[image]

**Error message i got when i watch the files using grunt:watch command**

Answer (score 0):

Every .less file name is defined to the _(underscore) in your case, your file name is without an underscore, like `custom.less` so, grunt will not specify the file and give an error when you run the command. rename your filename to `_custom.less` then perform the grunt command.